# In MySQL, how do we return count() without using window functions

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table named tracks:

```
user_id | track_id | music_type
.
.
.
.
```

The track_id is the primary key and and user_id is the person that uploaded the track and genre can be 'hiphop', 'rock', 'pop', 'electronic','trance' etc.

I need to get the total count(track_id) for each user where genre is either 'rock' or 'pop'.

I can do it with by using window function:

```
select user_id, count(track_id) as total_tracks
from tracks
where genre = 'rock' or genre = 'pop'
group by user_id
;
```

But how do I do it without using any window functions. Is intersect a way to do it or doing a self-join?

Comment: In this code there is no window function. It's a simple group by and aggregation. The most suitable and efficient way to do what you need.

Comment: About window functions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html

Comment: Thank you. So I was doing it without using window functions. Thanks for clearing the confusion. What if I have to use window function to get the desired output, how do I proceed?

Comment: You don't. Read about window functions in the above link. Your query is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: What window function?